# iframes como ajustar width y heght

Tags: html, css, iframe

No se me ajustan los width y height de iframes y no se si es por ser un iframe de spotify. Aca dejo el codigo. Puse como div principal un iframes y despues coloque las etiquetas iframe

`````
        <iframe class="jsparty-pod" src="https://open.spotify.com/embed-podcast/show/2ySVrxGkN6n6frMTo9Nsrt" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
        <iframe class="sintax-pod" src="https://open.spotify.com/embed-podcast/show/4kYCRYJ3yK5DQbP5tbfZby" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
          <iframe class="rework-pod" src="https://open.spotify.com/embed-podcast/show/5JxcIaIkN8zx3Zy7yD9snv" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
          <iframe class="ruby-pod" src="https://open.spotify.com/embed-podcast/show/2Iibd5A6R7mxkCm4NwNmUn" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
    </div>

    .iframes{
      position: absolute;
      top:127px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      margin-left:11px;
      }
    iframe{

        width:298px;
        height:225px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        overflow-y:hidden;

      }````
`````

Comment: ¿Quieres que el contenido del iframe se ajuste al alto y ancho establecido?

Comment: si ya que cuando lo veo se muestra como marcos en los extremos, pero no se aplica el valor que quiero